# Training Hidden Markov Model in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, hidden-markov-models, supervised-learning

Is it possible to train Hidden Markov Model in R?
I have a set of observations with its corresponding labels. And I need to train HMM in order to get the Markov parameters (i.e. the transition probabilities matrix, emission probabilities matrix and initial distribution). So, I can predict for the future observations.

In other words, I need the opposite of Forward_Backward Algorithm..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you do some web search before? Please have a look at [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. R is a good tool for simulation and statistical analysis. There are many nice packages available. You do not need to implement at all (of course you can), just learn to use them.

An example of using [package](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2014/03/r-and-hidden-markov-models.html).

An example of implementing HMM is [here](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-bioinformatics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/chapter10.html). Here DNA sequence is modeled using HMM.

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696547/hidden-markov-models-package-in-r) as well.